# A break is needed between two URLs if they include $ (if the site is mathjax enabled)

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> [image]

vs

> [image]

[Link to post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/74873/revisions).

Thanks to @MarkKirby for identifying that a line break solves it (first time that was needed for me).

I'm guessing [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), unless there's a fix for it. I'll leave it here in case it helps others.

But now I'm wondering if a single URL has two or more $'s, here a `\` won't solve it as it will break the URL.

@EmilJeřábek3.0 suggested [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the $ as a workaround (when two or more exist per URL). I wonder if that can also be the *fix,* i.e., if the URL is hyperlinked using the button, automatically it would convert each $ to %24.

Comment: That's curious. If I copy-paste that URL myself, and try to include it in an answer, the preview works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @ErikA: interesting, I'm on firefox, I added its tag

Comment: It works fine for me on Firefox, both link render correctly. How did you add them? Did you manually format them or use the hyperlink button on the editor?

Comment: @MarkKirby: yep, used the button

Comment: Same as me then. What site are you trying to post on?

Comment: @MarkKirby: the [aviation site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), in the bottom-right corner it's the same rev as MSE.

Comment: @MarkKirby: can you test hyperlinking both URLs?

Comment: OK the problem is between your [1] and [2] links in the screenshot you need to add a break line (press enter) and then it works for me but without the break it does not.

Comment: @MarkKirby: many thanks, updated the post.

Comment: Glad it got sorted, strange thing is other sites (I tried here and Ask Ubuntu) don't need the line break and I don't know why.

Comment: @MarkKirby: figured it out ;) see update

Comment: A work-around is to percent-encode the `$` (that is, replace it with `%24`). This also works if there are more of them in the same URL.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek3.0 great idea, and can also be used to fix the issue, I'll update the post

Comment: Do you want to include the %24 in the update so it is easier for people to find?

Comment: @mdewey: sure, thanks

Comment: percent-encoding the `$` isn't strictly correct (though works in many cases), apparently: https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/412/218